# Почему иногда может прийти неполный JSON?

Tags: ios, сокет, swift, tcp

Разобрался с библиотекой `SwiftSocket`, посылаю запрос серверу, получаю ответ. Но есть одно но! Пробовал несколько раз подряд запустить программу и увидел, что иногда прилетает неполный `JSON`. Я знаю, что мне должно прийти 385 объектов, в большинстве случает так и происходит, но порой не хватает последнего кусочка - например может прийти 340 и на этом все.
Вот кусок кода, где я обращаюсь к серверу и читаю ответ:

```
    var client:TCPClient = TCPClient(addr: "myIP", port: myPort)
    var (success, errmsg) = client.connect(timeout: 1)
    if success {
        var (success, errmsg) = client.send(str:"<Command=GetStudentList>\n" )
        if success {
            while(true)
            {
                var data = client.read(2048*10)
                if (data == nil)
                {
                    break
                }
                if let d = data {
                     if let str = String(bytes: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                        print(str)
                    }
                }

            }
        }else {
            print(errmsg)
        }
    } else {
        print(errmsg)
    }


}
```

В чем может быть проблема? 
Вот код сервера:

```
        int port = 8005;
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        bool fl = true;
        try
        {
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server is running, waiting connections...");
            while (fl)
            {
                const int bufferSize = 8192;
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
                Console.WriteLine("Have a client!!");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int readBytes = 0;

                 MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                 do
                 {
                     readBytes = clientStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     memStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                 } while (clientStream.DataAvailable);

                 buffer = memStream.GetBuffer();

                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                string command = message.Substring(message.IndexOf('<'), message.IndexOf('>') + 1);  
                message = message.Remove(0, message.IndexOf('>') + 1);
                string answer = "";

                switch (command)
                {
                    case "<Command=GetStudentList>":
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ":" + "Request received {0}. Doing...", command);
                            answer = DataBaseRequest.GetStudentList();
                            //fl = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    case "<Command=SendEvent>":
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ":" + "Request received {0}. Doing...", command);
                            answer = DataBaseRequest.SendEventToDataBase(message);
                            //fl = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    case "<Command=SendMessage>":
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ":" + "Request received {0}. Doing...", command);
                            answer = DataBaseRequest.SendMessageToDataBase(message);
                            break;
                        }
                    case "<Command=SendDeadline>":
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ":" + "Request received {0}. Doing...", command);
                            answer = DataBaseRequest.SendDeadlineToDataBase(message);
                            break;
                        }
                    case "<Command=SendTask>":
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ":" + "Request received {0}. Doing...", command);
                            answer = DataBaseRequest.SendTaskToDataBase(message);
                            break;
                        }
                    case "<Command=CheckUser>":
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ":" + "Request received {0}. Doing...", command);
                            answer = DataBaseRequest.CheckUser(message);
                            break;
                        }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ":" + "Using the database is successfully completed, there is a sending client response.");
                byte[] responseBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(answer);
                clientStream.Write(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
                clientStream.Close();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

Сервер крутится на виртуалке от Amazon - EC2

Comment: а может сервер так присылает? Ручками проверяли?

Comment: @KoVadim Да, конечно. Я пошагово каждый раз выполнял. В массиве байтов эти данные лежат. Почему-то не проходит вот эту проверку: 
`if let str = String(bytes: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` Причем, у меня есть  WinForms клиент, который при запуске посылает точно такой же запрос, и вот туда данные **всегда** прилетают целиком.

Comment: может оно просто больше 20480 байт? или просто нужно читать правильно.

Comment: Безусловно. Поэтому тут бесконечный цикл с проверкой - пока в `data` что-то считалось, происходят дальнейшие действия. Как только туда ничего не считалось - выход. Что Вы подразумеваете под "Нужно читать правильно"?

Comment: а предыдущие данные то теряются. Вы никак их не складываете.

Comment: я их вывожу в консоль - на данном этапе я просто хотел проверить все ли мне доходит. Как оказалось - не всегда.

Comment: В большинстве библиотек read c сокета/файла не объязан вычитать весь буфер,  он может хоть один байт прочитать и это будет нормально. На вин приложении скорее всего работает, так как сервер и клиент находиться на одной машине. 

Но Вы ещё код сервера не показывали.  Неведомо, что там ещё.

Comment: @KoVadim добавил код сервера. Насчет read с сокета - окей, даже если он считал хоть один байт - это разве проблема? Swift просто должен будет перевести этот байт в строку и вывести в консоль, а затем продолжить действия в цикле.

Comment: запустите сервер локально и смотрите, что он посылает. И можете через прокси смотреть на клиенте, что туда приходит